# Arithmetic on array of timestamps without year, month, day

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I am working with a large CSV file that I read with Pandas. One of the columns (not the Index) is timestamp data that look like this:

```
sent>23:56:51.748912
```

There is the prefix `sent>` followed by hour, minute, seconds, microseconds. I want to modify all of these timestamp entries so that the times are shifted backwards by 11 hours. So the example above would look like this:

```
sent>12:56:51.748912
```

I'm expecting/hoping that there is something smart enough with modulo arithmetic so that time shifting an entry of `sent>09:02:13.245511` backwards by 11 will become `sent>22:02:13.245511`.

I am having some difficulty because both the NumPy [`datetime64`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) and Pandas [`TimeSeries`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) want the full year, month, and day, but I don't have any of that. The documentation and examples I have seen so far have been rather terse. I've tried storing the data in all sorts of various structures (summarized below), but nothing seems to work so far.

(Still learning numpy/pandas... please go easy on me...) Here is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter=' ', skiprows=2, 
                 skipfooter=2, names=colnames, index_col=False, engine='python')

senttime_col = np.array(df['sent_time'], dtype='str')
senttime_col = np.char.lstrip(senttime_col, 'sent>')
# this creates np array of strings with elements like: 23:56:51.748585

senttimes_ts = pd.to_datetime(df['sent_time'])
# this creates TimeSeries with elements like: sent>23:56:51.748585

senttimes_ts.tshift(pd.Timedelta('-11 hours'))
# ValueError: Freq was not given and was not set in the index

senttimes_df = pd.DataFrame(senttime_col, index=None)
senttimes_df.shift(periods=-11, freq=pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.int64' and 'Timedelta'

senttimes = np.datetime64(senttime_col)
# ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime

senttimes = np.datetime64(senttime_col, 'h:m:s.us') 
# TypeError: Invalid datetime unit "h:m:s.us" in metadata
senttimes = np.array(senttime_col, dtype='datetime64[us]')
# ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "00:16:51.748269" at position 2

timelist = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f') for x in senttime_col]
# ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, `s` is your column as a series:

```
s = pd.Series(['sent>12:56:51.748912'] * 10000)

# this removes the 'sent>' string from the beginning
s = s.str[5:]
```

I'll use this function to lookup dates which I've already parsed -

```
def lookup2(s):
    '''uses .map() to apply changes'''
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) - pd.Timedelta('11 hours') for date in s.unique()}
    return s.map(dates)
```

Then, we save the result back into `s`. Note: I didn't face this problem - "I am having some difficulty because both the NumPy datetime64 and Pandas TimeSeries want the full year, month, and day, but I don't have any of that."

```
s = lookup2(s)

In [156]: s.head()
Out[156]: 
0   2015-05-10 12:56:51.748912
1   2015-05-10 12:56:51.748912
2   2015-05-10 12:56:51.748912
3   2015-05-10 12:56:51.748912
4   2015-05-10 12:56:51.748912
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Moving time back by 11 hours -

```
In [154]: t = (s - pd.Timedelta('11 hours')).dt.time

In [155]: t.head()
Out[155]: 
0    23:56:51.748912
1    23:56:51.748912
2    23:56:51.748912
3    23:56:51.748912
4    23:56:51.748912
dtype: object
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. This almost worked, but it looks like the time shift was 11 hours forward rather than backward:
`s.head(1)
Out[4]: 
0   2015-05-09 23:56:51.748585
Name: sent_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

t.head(1)
Out[5]: 
0    10:56:51.748585
dtype: object`

Comment: Found it... there was a "double negative". Just need a `+` rather than `-`: `s.apply(lambda v: v + pd.Timedelta('-11 hours')).dt.time`. But otherwise very great, thank you! It does take a few minutes to process ~650K entries.

Comment: Hmmm. Your best bet in python for date-time conversion is a lookup. Take a look at these benchmarks - https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse

Comment: Thanks. I should clarify: the call to `lookup2()` returns very quickly. It is the `s.apply()` line that takes a while. I didn't time it, but ~15 sec on 650K entries.

Comment: Ah! In that case, let me try and combine both. Right now, you don't have a reason to re-run them separately.

Comment: you can simply do a vectorized: ``s-pd.Timedelta('11 hours')``, no need for apply